# How to see the logcat into android x86

Tags: android, linux, terminal, android-x86, live-cd

I am using android-x86 2.2 version as a live cd, adb tool is not avilable to see logcat so suggest some alternative to see system logs.

Comment: aren't u using eclipse for android???

Comment: what do you mean by live cd? only ndk will differ from arm and X86? can you provide more info.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I have downloaded .iso image from `http://www.androidx86.org/downloads.html` and made bootable live-cd of it.At the time of running Android-x86 froyo from cd-rom from the console want to see the logs.

Comment: @Haps no, I am using android-x86 as a operating system and through the console of it want to see logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution to see the log first press <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd> then write logcat at the terminal then hit enter you will be able to see logs.